# Firestore Rules Simulator - Resource undefined

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying to use the new Rules Simulator Tool provided by firebase, however I'm having problems getting it to work

When setting the path like this in the simulator panel

```
/users/Gd9jd3jd8sSixxx38djSs
```

And then selecting the authentication options and inputting the uid of the authorised user as the same string Gd9jd3jd8sSixxx38djSs. I'm getting the following error when using this firestore rule

```
match /users/{user}{
     allow read: if request.auth.uid == resource.id
}
```

"Error: simulator.rules line [4], column [41]. Property id is undefined on object. "

This document does exist inside my firestore database and is in the correct path specified.

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It sounds like you just want to use the `user` placeholder you defined:

```
 allow read: if request.auth.uid == user
```

Comment: That works perfectly, thankyou. However I'm really confused as to why the resource.id isn't working. I thought the resource was referring to the document that the rule is being performed on. So would it still not work the other way?

Comment: If there is no actual document in the database that matches, there will be no id.

Comment: @DougStevenson : im getting same issue but for - request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.userID;  
Error: simulator.rules line [8], column [38]. Property resource is undefined on object.

Comment: @BishalGhimire  you're getting that error in the simulator because you probably didn't click the build  document option to create a document before runing the simulation. it was the cause of the error for me. i hope it helps