# FireStore Rules - creating rules with joining multiple collection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

i am fresher on fire base and fire store rules

i am trying to create fire store rules but not  success :(

i want to display the details based on the rules

i am showing my collection details

[image: raches]

[image: mobile_user_raches]

here my requirement is , i want to set rules for mobile_user_raches for getting the documents that is equal to the company_id and active_user_id from the request, the active_user_id  is equal to the documentID

then i want here following the details i got a document from mobile_user_raches  and that include a set of ranch_ids , then i want to get the details from collection raches, that the 'id' in  raches (same as the documentId )is equal to the raches_ids from the  'mobile_user_raches' document

**i will show my requirement in an example
in my mobile_user_ranches image, if 1120 is logged in , he has a list of ranch_ids in that collection
if we access mobile_user_ranches collection the user is need to show only one record that is 1120(documentid)
if we try to use the othe collection 'ranches' , the loggind user is 1120 so, he can only visible the ranches details having the ids
289
290
291
132
292
these are defined in mobile_user_ranches , in ranchids**

i want to write rule for raches collection

where the id is equal to the ranch_ids from 'mobile_user_raches'

i tried this but showing error

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
     match /{mobile_user_raches}/{userId}/{document=**} {
            allow read : if  request.auth.uid == resource.data.active_user_id;
     }
    match /{raches}/{userId}/{document=**} {
            allow read : if resource.data.id in (get(/databases/$(database)/documents/mobile_user_raches/$(request.auth.uid)/ranch_ids/{ranchid}));
    }
    }
}
```

i tried this one also

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{ranches}/{userId} {
            allow read :  if resource.data.id in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/mobile_user_raches/$(request.auth.uid)).data.ranch_ids
            // allow read :  if exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/mobile_user_raches/$(request.auth.uid));
    }
    }
```

i tried this one also

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{ranches}/{ranch} {
    allow read :  if request.resource.data.id in  get(/databases/$(database)/documents/mobile_user_ranches/$(request.auth.uid)).data.ranch_ids;
    }
    }
```

in this time i got this error

```
   Error: simulator.rules line [5], column [22]. Property resource is undefined on object
```

.

this is my latest try.

how can i this?

does any idea about this ?

i have no idea how to use get this

i am getting no idea.

anyone help me

Comment: To start, can you show the error?

Comment: @MrTech yes.. i updated the question .. i tried different methods but not getting any idea.

Comment: To move this along, please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51874357/firestore-rules-simulator-resource-undefined  I believe it may help you along. Let me know otherwise.

Comment: @MrTech Thank you but that is not i want..  could you please look my question

Comment: I see that sometimes you use raches instead of ranches. A typo. I'm thinking this may cause a problem with your code.

Comment: @MrTech no.. i changed into ranches , but not getting.. i think the logic i trying to implement is not property implemented..  i didnt get any details related to my requirement

Comment: To help you along, I've found a resource that explains generally what you may want to do https://www.thetopsites.net/article/50083274.shtml

Comment: I've also found this link that explains joins https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64055384/firestore-join-one-document-with-another-list-document

Comment: @MrTech Not satisfying my requirement

Comment: I've found the basic syntax of Cloud Firestore rules here that may help you. https://medium.com/@khreniak/cloud-firestore-security-rules-basics-fac6b6bea18e

Comment: @MrTech i think i am looking for the wrong view..i am  trying to figure out filtering , i think its not possible.

Comment: If you are wanting information about filtering, please look at https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/queries