# Firestore: Join one document with another list document

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've been working with firestore and I'm trying to make a query between two documents, this is the scenario:

1. I have a document called user and it contains name and rate attributes
   ex: user = {name: 'homer simpson', rate 4.5}
2. I have a document called events and it contains idUser, name, date (timestamp), state
   ex: event = {name: 'class one', date: 'September 25, 2020 at 10:00:00 AM UTC-5', idUser: '1345648fdsfds', state: 'ACTIVE'}

**One user can have several events**

I'd like to get 20 user with these conditions:
a. They should have events between today and next two weeks
b. They should be ordered by rate

I've been trying to make a query for this but really I haven't been able to do it, maybe someone can tell me how can I do it or maybe give some ideas.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Firestore does not offer any SQL-like joins.  You can query only a single collection at a time.  If you need to join, you will need to perform additional queries to get the matching documents from another collection.

For this reason, it's common in NoSQL databases to duplicate data between collections in order to reduce the number of queries.  The downside is that you have to perform multiple updates when data changes.  You will have to decide which approach you want to take.

Comment: Thank you Doug for your answer, what do you think if I put event document as an array inside user document, do you think there is a way to do this kind of query?

**ex:** 
`user { name: 'homer simpson',rate 4.5, events: [{name: 'class one', date: 'September 25, 2020 at 10:00:00 AM UTC-5', state: 'ACTIVE'}]}`

Comment: If you put everything required in one document, then yes.

Comment: Thank you Doug, sorry maybe could you give me an example, please

Comment: I suggest giving your own example a try to see if it works the way you want.